# .NET project with native dependencies. How to set build configuration?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build

Let's say my solution contains two projects *A* and *B*. Project *A* has reference to project *B*. Project *B* has reference to a 3rd party assembly *C*. *C* depends on some native dlls - they should be placed in the same directory as *C* assembly in order for *C* to work.

What I want to achieve is following: when I build project *A* it's build directory should contain next files:

```
A.dll
B.dll
C.dll
Native_Lib_For_C_1.dll
...
Native_Lib_For_C_N.dll
```

**What options do I have?**

I have tried to write Post-Build action for project *B* to copy native dlls to output directory. But when I build *A* native dlls are going to *B*'s output directory, not *A*'s one.

Sure I can write same Post-Build action for project *A*, but it violates DRY principle because in fact I have many projects like *A*, *B* and *C* in my solution.

Another option is to set same output directory for all my projects, but it's not ideal solution because I prefer if some of the projects build into their own directories.

Comment: So eventually my solution is to write windows shell scrip (.cmd file) with commands copying required files to destination directory. Destination directory is passed to the script as parameter. Then this script is called from post-build actions of projects. PS. Why can't I answer my own question?